# Concatenate strings with a common substring in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Input

```
ONESTRING
STRINGTHREE
THREEFOUR 
FOURFIVE
```

Output

```
ONESTRINGTHREEFOURFIVE
```

in python??

I think first i concatenate with 2 string then run a loop but this gives an error I don't know why can anyone help in in python?

Comment: This can be anywhere from trivial to quite complicated, depending on your use-case and constraints. Are your strings already in the order in which they should be joined? Do you know the common substrings *a priori*? Or do you need to search all strings for common substrings and then join them in the correct order?

Comment: I don't know the common substring I just want to return a string that concatenates all strings use in input and common substring use only once

Comment: Have any of the provided answers helped you? If so, please accept one so that this question can be removed from the unanswered queue!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 3):

### WARNING

This solution is for a list of strings ***in arbitrary order.*** This means that EVERY possible pair of words must be checked for a common substring, which may require an enormous amount of memory if your list of strings is large.

### Solution 1, allows for words with no common substrings to be concatenated if desired

```py
import itertools
from typing import Set, Tuple, Dict, List


def get_match(pair: Tuple[str, str], min_overlap: int = 3) -> str:
    a, b = pair
    for i in range(min_overlap, min(map(len, pair)) + 1):
        if a[-i:] == b[:i]:
            return b[:i]
    return ""


def links_joiners(strings: List[str]) -> Tuple[Dict[str, str], Set[str]]:
    links, joiners = dict(), set()
    for pair in itertools.permutations(strings, 2):
        if (match := get_match(pair)):
            joiners.add(match)
            links.update((pair,))
    return links, joiners


def get_ordered_strings(strings: List[str], links: Dict[str, str]) -> List[str]:
    def find_order(node: str) -> int:
        return 0 if node not in links else 1 + find_order(links[node])
    return sorted(strings, key=find_order, reverse=True)


def join_strings(strings: List[str], joiners: Set[str]) -> str:
    s = "".join(strings)
    for j in joiners:
        s = s.replace(j, "", 1)
    return s
```

Usage:

```py
strings = ["THREEFOUR",
           "ONESTRING",
           "STRINGTHREE",
           "FOURFIVE"]

links, joiners = get_links_and_joiners(strings)
ordered_strings = get_ordered_strings(strings, links)
join_strings(ordered_strings, joiners)
```

Output:

```py
'ONESTRINGTHREEFOURFIVE'
```

### Explanation

First, `itertools` is part of the standard library; no need to install any third party packages for this solution.

Now, the `links_joiners()` function will take a list of strings and find all the pairs of strings with matching suffix-prefix pairs, putting those pairs into a `links` dictionary which looks like this:

```py
{'ONESTRING': 'STRINGTHREE',
 'THREEFOUR': 'FOURFIVE',
 'STRINGTHREE': 'THREEFOUR'}
```

Notice these are not in order. This is because for an arbitrary list of strings we can't be sure the strings were in order in the first place, so we have to iterate over every permutation of `strings` exhaustively in order to ensure that we've covered all pairings.

Now, notice there's also a function called `get_ordered_strings()` with an inner function `find_order()`. The function `get_ordered_strings()` forms what is known as a closure, but that's not particularly important to understand right now. The `find_order()` function is recursive, here's how it works:

1. Given a `node`, if the `node` is not a key in the `links` dictionary we've reached the base case and return zero. Otherwise, move to step 2.
2. If `node` *is* present, add one to a recursive call to `find_order` on that new node.

So given a key, say `"ONESTRING"`, the `find_order()` function will look at the value associated with that key, and if that value is also a key in the dictionary, look at *its* value, and so on until it reaches a value that isn't a key in the dictionary.

Here's the code for `find_order()` again:

```py
def find_order(node: str) -> int:
    if node not in links:
        return 0
    return 1 + find_order(links[node])
```

And here's what `links` looks like after calling `links_joiners()`:

```py
{'ONESTRING': 'STRINGTHREE',
 'THREEFOUR': 'FOURFIVE',
 'STRINGTHREE': 'THREEFOUR'}
```

Now trace an example call to `find_order("ONESTRING")`:

```py
find_order("ONESTRING") = 1 + find_order("STRINGTHREE")
                        = 1 + (1 + find_order("THREEFOUR"))
                        = 1 + (1 + (1 + find_order("FOURFIVE")))  # Base case
                        = 1 + (1 + (1 + 0))
                        = 3
```

What this function is doing is finding how many pairwise connections can be made from a given starting string. Another way to think of it is that `links` is actually representing adjacencies in a (special case of a) [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph).

Essentially what we want to do is take the nodes `THREEFOUR`, `ONESTRING`, `STRINGTHREE`, `FOURFIVE` and construct the longest possible singly-linked list (a type of a DAG) from them:

```py
ONESTRING -> STRINGTHREE -> THREEFOUR -> FOURFIVE
```

By passing a given "node" of this graph to `find_order()`, it will follow the graph all the way to the end. So `ONESTRING` travels a distance of `3` to get to the end, whereas `THREEFOUR` travels only a distance of `1`.

```py
Node:   ONESTRING -> STRINGTHREE -> THREEFOUR -> FOURFIVE
Dist:       3             2             1            0
```

Now, by passing `find_order` to the built-in `sorted()` function, we can tell Python how we want our `strings` to be sorted, which, in this case is in reverse order, by distance. The result is this:

```py
>>> strings = ['THREEFOUR', 'ONESTRING', 'STRINGTHREE', 'FOURFIVE']
>>> ordered_strings = get_ordered_strings(strings, links)
>>> ordered_strings
['ONESTRING', 'STRINGTHREE', 'THREEFOUR', 'FOURFIVE']
```

Now, by joining each string by their common substrings, we are constructing the longest possible string where the constraint is that each pair of strings must have a common substring in the correct position. In other words, `ordered_strings` represents the *longest path* in the DAG. Or more accurately, we've *designed* a DAG which will have the longest path, by using all the provided nodes, and putting them in the correct order.

From here, we join each string:

```py
>>> s = "".join(ordered_strings)
>>> s
'ONESTRINGSTRINGTHREETHREEFOURFOURFIVE'
```

Then we remove one instance of each of the joiners:

```py
for j in joiners:
    s = s.replace(j, "", 1)
```

### Solution 2, only concatenates overlapping strings

This solution reuses `join_strings()` and `get_match()` from above. It also uses the walrus operator `:=` (Python 3.8+) but can easily be written without it.

```py
def join_overlapping_pairs(strings: List[str]) -> str:
    if len(strings) == 1:
        return strings.pop()
    matches = set()
    for pair in itertools.permutations(strings, 2):
        if (match := get_match(pair)):
            matches.add(join_strings(pair, (match,)))
    return join_overlapping_pairs(matches)
```

Comment: But This is a brute force for this input data is there any way to concatenate many no of strings with single-time use of  common substring

Comment: I think he want something more generic :)

Comment: i want to concatenate all the string with a single-time use of common substring

Comment: yes i want generic

Comment: @KAVITASINGH see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Here is generic solution according your provided example. Sequence must be ordered, otherwise it will not work.

```
from functools import reduce

s = [
    "ONESTRING",
    "STRINGTHREE",
    "THREEFOUR",
    "FOURFIVE",
]

def join_f(first, add):
    i = 1
    while add[:i] in first:
        i += 1
    return first + add[i-1:]

print(reduce(join_f, s))
```

Comment: This'll only work if `s` is already in pairing order.

Comment: Yes of course, if sequence is not in correct order this will not be easy and the problem will have O(n*(n-1)) complexity.

Comment: Yep, hence why I'm hesitant to do any more work until OP provides more detail.

Comment: I agree. Example sounds as nice problem from hiring interview, so I accepted the challenge. No more effort from my side, as well.

Comment: I ended up going full ham and generalized to an unordered arbitrary list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

May use difflib library, sample code for your reference

```
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

str1 = "ONESTRING"
str2 = "STRINGTHREE"

match = SequenceMatcher(None, str1, str2).find_longest_match(0, len(str1), 0, len(str2))
#match[a]=3, match[b]=0, match[size]=6
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the words are in the connecting order:

```
words = ['ONESTRING',
         'STRINGTHREE',
         'THREEFOUR', 
         'FOURFIVE']

S = words[0]
for w in words[1:]:
    S += w[next(i for i in range(1,len(w)) if S.endswith(w[:-i])):]

print(S)
'ONESTRINGTHREEFOURFIVE'
```

If the words are not in connecting order, a recursive approach can do it:

```
def combine(words,S=""):
    if not words: return S
    result = ""                       # result is shortest combo
    for i,w in enumerate(words):      # p is max overlap (end/start)
        p = next((i for i in range(1,len(w)) if S.endswith(w[:-i])),0)
        if result and not p: continue                  # check if can combine
        combo = combine(words[:i]+words[i+1:],S+w[p:]) # candidate combo
        if not result or len(combo)<len(result):       # keep if shortest
            result = combo or result
    return result
```

Output:

```
words = ['ONESTRING',
         'FOURFIVE',
         'THREEFOUR',
         'STRINGTHREE'
         ]

result = combine(words)    
print(result)
'ONESTRINGTHREEFOURFIVE
```